# How can I execute scripts in a code created powershell shell that has Host.Ui.prompt commands in it?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell Commandlet which prompts a user from a secure string based on a condition. Now I want to automate the testing of this commandlet for which I use a Powershell Remote Runspace to Invoke the commandlet. Currently it fails with this error.

```
Write-Host : A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type       does not support user interaction. Try a host program that supports user interaction, such as the Windows PowerShell Console or Windows PowerShell ISE, and remove prompt-related commands from command types that do not support user interaction, such as Windows PowerShell workflows.
```

How can I automate this?

Comment: Is this cmdlet something you wrote? It would help to see some code. In principle all input to a function should be through parameters. This makes it easy to automate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running powershell via c#. You can't prompt the user for input from the powershell script. You either need to pre-provide the necessary info in the script, or prompt for the info from your application and then pass the info to the powershell script.

As ojk mentioned the easiest way to accomplish this would probably be to use a powershell function then pass the necessary parameters to it via the code.